# How does tcp/udp connection works?

Tags: networking, tcp, dns, udp, router

I would like to ask a general newbie question. I understand that for a computer in location A to connect to a server in location B, packets of data have to be sent to multiple data centers through multiple gateways and through multiple verification channels to ensure the connection request finds the right destination.

However after the connection is established, when the computer and the server send/receive data, do these data still need to go through [multiple data centers through multiple gateways and through multiple verification channels]?

Comment: While TCP requires connections, UDP is an explicitly _connectionless_ protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Every TCP / UDP packet can have a different network path between source to destination. However the connection establishment of a TCP connection being stateful is all about what packet size, compression method etc.

At network layer- Connection is stateless.  Please read about OSI model in detail also you can refer to this https://www.ccnahub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/watermarked-pc1-comm.jpg  It has good explanation of how OSI works.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP packet being sent from computer A to computer B will be addressed to a particular IP address.  If that TCP address is not on the local LAN, it will go first through the local LAN to whatever is designated as the local gateway.  That gateway then sends it on over the connection to an external network.  At that point, it will be delivered to some router in your ISP.  That router will look at the destination IP address and consult a routing table to find where it should next send the packet.  That will typically be another router elsewhere in the network.  This continues and (assuming good routing tables in each router) the packet will get closer to its end desination on each hop.  Eventually, the packet will get to a router that has a routing table that knows about either the actual IP address or the home gateway for that IP address and the packet will be sent to that gateway.  That home gateway can then deliver the packet to that actual IP address.  In some cases, there may be a private network at either end where private IP addresses/port combinations are converted to public IP addresses and vice versa.

If computer A sends multiple packets to computer B, they do not have to all go the exact same path, though typically they will (assuming no problems or congestion in the network between the two endpoints).

In this scenario where A and B are on different private networks, there is no direct connection between computer A and computer B so each packet has to follow the path from one router to the next until it arrive at the final gateway and then destination address.

> However after the connection is established, when the computer and the server send/receive data, do these data still need to go through [multiple data centers through multiple gateways and through multiple verification channels]?

If the routers are doing their job appropriately, the very first packet takes the most efficient path from A to B that the network knows.  There is no "better" way to send subsequent packets.  Subsequent packets will follow the same process (to a router, router looks up in routing table where to send for next hop and so on).  If the two endpoints are a long ways apart (in terms of network topology), then the packet may go through many routers.  Routers are highly optimized pieces of equipment capable of passing off millions of packets a second as this is how data moves on any TCP/IP network like the internet.

There is no difference in how the first packet that initiates the TCP connection flows versus subsequent packets.  At the network level, they are just packets traveling from a source IP address to a destination IP address.  Once the connection is established, a reliability layer will be started to track packets that might get lost, initiate retransmissions, etc... but this doesn't have anything to do with how a given packet gets from A to B.